# Group 1 is not followed by group 2

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression like this:

```
((?:(?<![^aoeiu])(?:y)|[^aoeuiy])*)([ioeua]+(?:(?<![^aoeiu])(?:y)|[^aoeuiy])+)*([ioeua]*)
```

This is how it looks on [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/) for easier visualizing:
[image]

And this is the result I got from [pythex.org](https://pythex.org/) when testing it with the string `private`:

**Match 1:**
1. `pr`
2. `at`
3. `e`

**Match 2:**
1. empty
2. none
3. empty

I have two problems with the result:

1. I was expecting group 1, group 2, group 3 to be `pr`, `ivat`, `e` respectively. However, it's not in the result.
2. From my understanding, if group 1 contains something and so does group 2, concatenating these two groups will yield a string which is a sub string of `private`. However, in Match 1 (concatenating yields `prat`), I don't see the letter `i`. Why is that?

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: It would be nice to know what your pattern is supposed to be doing, unless this is a purely academic question, in which case you should mention that.

Comment: I am working on the PorterStemmer algorithm, in which I try to capture the groups in this structure [C](VC){m}[V] of a random word. C and V mean consomants and vowels. The exact definition of the structure and notations are explained in the section 2 of this page: [PorterStemmer](https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/def.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you gave works as expected,

In the first match your second group captures the last VC iteration in the center of the word (since you entered the greedy asterisk * after the group brackets), perhaps you meant:

```
((?:(?<![^aoeiu])(?:y)|[^aoeuiy])*)((?:[ioeua]+(?:(?<![^aoeiu])(?:y)|[^aoeuiy])+)*)([ioeua]*)
```

instead?

As for the second empty match, replacing asterisks (might this actually be a legal Consonant cluster in English?) with the plus signs makes that go away quite neatly

```
((?:(?<![^aoeiu])(?:y)|[^aoeuiy])+)((?:[ioeua]+(?:(?<![^aoeiu])(?:y)|[^aoeuiy])+)+)([ioeua]+)
```

tried out on https://regex101.com/

Comment: Yes. The first regex that you mentioned is what I really want. Thank you.